# Calculation/ Implementation of the real 3D Intersection over Union (IoU) of two Bounding Boxes with 9 Degrees of Freedom

Tags: 3d, computer-vision, object-detection, metrics, bounding-box

I have two 3D bounding boxes with 9 degrees of freedom (3 translation, 3 dimensions, 3 rotations). Now I want to calculate the Intersection over Union (IoU) also known as [Jaccard Index](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jaccard_index) of them:

[image: Intersection Volume divided by Union Volume]

I know this has [already](https://www.researchgate.net/profile/Dingfu_Zhou/publication/335135103_IoU_Loss_for_2D3D_Object_Detection/links/5d662370299bf1f70b124e0d/IoU-Loss-for-2D-3D-Object-Detection.pdf) [been](http://www.cvlibs.net/publications/Geiger2012CVPR.pdf) [implemented](https://varunagrawal.github.io/bbox/bbox.html#bbox.metrics.jaccard_index_3d) for the case of a single rotation (around the z-axis) using the bird's eye view, however I am looking for a solution, where the 3D bounding boxes can be rotated around all axes (x, y, z).

So far I did not find any approaches. I would probably start by calculating all intersection points and then try to calculate volumes using tetrahedrons. Any links or hints are welcome!

Comment: Hello! I am currently looking for answers to the same question. Do you have any updates on this?

Comment: Hi @NaphatAmundsen, I did not find a solution yet. However there are some papers like [RIoU](https://www.ecva.net/papers/eccv_2020/papers_ECCV/papers/123650460.pdf) or [3D-GIoU](https://www.mdpi.com/1424-8220/19/19/4093) that go into that direction and maybe provide a good starting point.
Also have a look at the [BOP Benchmark](https://bop.felk.cvut.cz/home/) for 6D Pose Estimation, they have some interesting metrics.

Answer (score 2):

You can find an [implementation](https://github.com/google-research-datasets/Objectron/blob/master/objectron/dataset/iou.py) for 3D-oriented bounding boxes accompanying the objectron benchmark. Their IoU metric takes two boxes as input and calculates the intersection volume based on the [Sutherland-Hodgman Polygon clipping algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sutherland%E2%80%93Hodgman_algorithm). A detailed answer is also described in the in the [paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2012.09988.pdf).